# Performance impact on trying to call methods on None in a loop

Tags: python, scientific-computing

Let's imagine the following code

```
from pymaybe import maybe

def compute_something():
return np.sin(2)

def foo(observer=None):
    observer = maybe(observer)
    for i in range(0, int(1e3)):
         something = compute_something()
         observer.observe(something)  # Comment this line for comparison
```

So basically I am attempting some kind of inversion of control where I pass an object implementing an interface (here a single method `observe`), but I want to leave the possibility that the user just pass nothing (default argument value is thus is defined as `maybe(None)`.

The question is: should I expect some performance impact?

I used `timeit` to compare the two (with and without the call to `observe`):

> Without a call to `observe`:
>
> 1.77 ms ± 5.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>
> With a call to `observe`:
>
> 3.27 ms ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The impact seems to be quite minimal and I assumed that `pymaybe` is just a try block, so I compared with the following code as well:

```
def foo(observer=None):
    observer = None
    for i in range(0, int(1e3)):
         something = compute_something()
         try:
             observer.observe(something)
         except:
            pass
foo()
```

With the following results:

> With a call to `observe`:
>
> 2.73 ms ± 66.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

So I conclude the following (no surprise):
   - `pymaybe` adds some overhead by being one additional layer around a `try` block
   - the `try` block itself has a non negligible impact on the performance

If my assumptions/conclusions above are correct, what would be a way to further improve the performance?

Shall I duplicate the code?

Is there a way to "remove" calls to methods on `None` at runtime (in a loop where the value won't change during the execution of the loop)?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an `if` statement...

Comment: @ScottHunter Humm... In that case will the test be done at each iteration of the loop? Or will it be optimized away?

Comment: @ScottHunter OK, brain failure on my side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach would be to use an `if` statement, as Scott Hunter has suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630322/performance-impact-on-trying-to-call-methods-on-none-in-a-loop#comment86267512_49630322):

```
def foo(observer=None):
    for i in range(0, int(1e3)):
         something = compute_something()
         if observer:
             observer.observe(something)
```

You could also use a wrapper around `observer.observe` that defaults to doing nothing:

```
def foo(observer=None):
    try:
        observe = observer.observe
    except AttributeError:
        def observe(x):
            pass
    for i in range(0, int(1e3)):
         something = compute_something()
         observe(something)
```

In my experiments, both approaches have similar running times.